# How to add padding between columns in Foundation Float grid?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, css-grid

I've been using Foundation 6 framework trying to create a small amount of padding between columns however I can't seem to find a solution, where am I going wrong?

[Here's an image explaining what I've got and what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGsnV.jpg)

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="column large-4 small-12">
            <P>Text1</P>
        </div>

        <div class="column large-4 small-12">
            <p>Text2</p>
        </div>

        <div class="column large-4 small-12">
            <p>Text3</p>
        </div>
    </div>


.column, .columns {
    border:red 1px solid;
    background-color:@menu-color;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Zurb Foundation, but see they use Flexbox. I've modified the code you've provided to use Flexbox, as well, though it's for layout purposes only. We're simply targeting the middle row item and providing it some left and right margin.

```css
.column,
.columns {
  border: red 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
   flex: 1;
}

.column:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column large-4 small-12">
    <P>Text1</P>
  </div>

  <div class="column large-4 small-12">
    <p>Text2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="column large-4 small-12">
    <p>Text3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ncL9wjbv/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add margin to the css instead of padding.

```
.column, .columns {
    border:red 1px solid;
    background-color:@menu-color;
    margin:5px;
}
```